# Two CPT: one is using part of the custom rewrite slug from the other

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, slug

I've these two CPT: Publications and Books.

The custom rewrite slug for `Publications`are just `/publications/`
I want the Books CPTs rewrite slug to be `/publications/books/`

But I do that and I get an 404 error when navigating to `site.com/publications/books/wordpress-is-great`

Most certainly be cause it is the publications rewrite rules which "step" in and not books but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work and "combining" parts of the rewrite slug for Publications.

Answer (score 0):

The URL reads as if books is a sub taxonomy of publications.

Try using 'publications-books'

Don't forget to re-save the permalinks in the settings -> permalinks options.